# how to display Case on my console app support page with all communication

Tags: case

I am trying to display Cases on my console application support page. Also, when a user replies on a Case from my application I want to display it on sales force UI( as CaseFeed or CaseComment or anything), so that support team can have a look and can give response , which in turn will be displayed on my application support page.
How do I manage this communication between sales force UI and my console app for a Case?

I tried CaseFeed ,CaseComments and email to case but they didn't work out for me.

CaseFeed : I can select CaseFeeds with FeedComments for a case but as per API creating or upserting CaseFeed is not possible. So I can't create a new CaseFeed when a user replies to a Case from my application.

CaseComment : CaseComments are not suposed to have comments under it so I can not manage communication between support team and user.

Email to case : creates a new EmailMessage which can't have comments under it. so its not useful to manage communication.

Am I doing something totally wrong? What's the generalized  way of integrating salesforce with your application support page?

Answer (score 1):

That's precisely what [Web-to-Case](http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=setting_up_web-to-case.htm) is for. Ensure that you have the right permissions as listed [here](http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_casecapture.htm&language=en_US). Then go to

```
Setup | Customize | Self-Service | Web-to-Case
```

and follow the steps to generate the HTML code that you can use on your web application support page.

Comment: Thank Gaurav.
How to manage the communication, after Case has been created? I mean can customer and support team put comments on a Case or is it supposed to be totally email based?